# The thing is if I target a ID it works but if I change the method to ...ElementsByClassName it doesn't?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = document.createElement("div");
a.setAttribute("class", "jsonfiles");
document.getElementById("row").appendChild(a);


var a = document.createElement("div");
a.setAttribute("class", "jsonfiles");
document.getElementsByClassName("row").appendChild(a);
```

//with ID it works, but when I change the target itself (in html) to class and change the method in js code it doesnt??

Comment: Can you show us the HTML where you have an element with the class `row`? Provide us a [mcve].

Comment: @csmckelvey HTML is not necessary to see in this case, see the answers.

Comment: The answers could be correct, but we can't know unless we know the HTML has an element with the class that is being searched for. If there is no element with that class then the answers aren't 100% correct.

Comment: OP states *when I change the target itself (in html) to class and change the method in js*. I think they do know they need to have a `class="row"`.

Comment: You can think it, but I want confirmation. No issue with that.

Comment: here is the HTML: <div class="row">

   <div class="col-lg-6">

    <div class="moviebox"></div>

   </div>

   <div class="col-lg-6">

    <div class="moviebox"></div>

   </div>

  </div>  <!---end of 2nd. row 2 img inside--->

  <div class="row">

   <div class="col-lg-6">

    <div class="moviebox"></div>

   </div>

   <div class="col-lg-6">

    <div class="moviebox"></div>
    
   </div>

  </div>

Comment: If I change the class to ID in the html and change the method in js to ...ElemntById.. it works! But with class in HTML and js ...ClassName.. it doesnt!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection  of elements that match that className. Unlike the `getElementById` ( notice the singular Element ) which returns the element with that id. `id`s should be unique so that's why it's just one element, but if someone adds multiple elements with same `id`s ( which is wrong ) , `getElementById` will select the first one.

Anyway, long story short, if you want to apply something to all elements that have a specific class you should loop through them ( just like an array)

```js
const nodeList = document.getElementsByClassName("row")

for (i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
  const a = document.createElement("div");
  a.setAttribute("class", "jsonfiles");
  nodeList[i].appendChild(a)
}
```

```css
.jsonfiles {
  height: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  aaa
</div>
<div class="row">
  vbb
</div>
<div class="row">
  vbb
</div>
<div class="row">
  vbb
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array like object so you need to pass the index to access the element

Try this

```
document.getElementsByClassName("row")[0].appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

From MDN documentation:

> The `getElementsByClassName` method of Document interface returns an array-like object of **all** child elements which have all of the given class names.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Notice the s in getElement**s**ByClassName?

It means that in contrast to `getElementById` (notice no 's' there, it returns a **single** element since there can be only **one** element with any given `id`) it returns *a number of elements* as an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). You can access the elements by index `i`, as with any array:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("row")[i]
```

where `i` starts at `0` for the first entry.